# Why is my JS regex matching more than it should?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a string like "https://open.spotify.com/track/1c3v8Ww4q8Vah92JBxAzxi?si=oqw6SQtxTVqJuoe2C_XrzQ omg this ones nice"
and extract the part after the last slash, in this case "1c3v8Ww4q8Vah92JBxAzxi?si=oqw6SQtxTVqJuoe2C_XrzQ". Could anyone help me figure out the regex with appropriate group for this? I already tried the following:

```
/.*spotify\.com.*/
/.*spotify\.com.\/track\/.*/
/.*spotify\.com.\/track.*/
/.*spotify\.com\.\/track.*/
/.*spotify\.com\.\/track\/.*/
/.*spotify\.com\..*/
/.*spotify\.com\/.*/
/.*spotify\.com\/track\/.*/
/.*spotify\.com\/track\/(.*)/
/.*spotify\.com\/track\/(.*)\s*/
/.*spotify\.com\/track\/(.*)\s*$/
/.*spotify\.com\/track\/(\S)*/
/.*?spotify\.com\/track\/(\S)*/
/\/(.*)?\s/
```

but it normally ends up matching the whole link like "https://open.spotify.com/track/1c3v8Ww4q8Vah92JBxAzxi?si=oqw6SQtxTVqJuoe2C_XrzQ"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like:

`\/track\/([^ ]*)`

https://regex101.com/r/PwRXlA/1

1. search for literal `/track/`
2. `[^ ]*` match everything until whitespace

as you tagged js:

```
'https://open.spotify.com/track/1c3v8Ww4q8Vah92JBxAzxi?si=oqw6SQtxTVqJuoe2C_XrzQ omg this ones nice'.match(/\/track\/([^ ]*)/)[1]
```

Output

> "1c3v8Ww4q8Vah92JBxAzxi?si=oqw6SQtxTVqJuoe2C_XrzQ"

Comment: I ended up having to stop at the first question mark, so changing yours to `/\/track\/([^?]*)/` worked great and I also didn't have to worry if it was a `\n` or other type of whitespace. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using `\w` will help you a lot here. It matches any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].

```
track = "https://open.spotify.com/track/1c3v8Ww4q8Vah92JBxAzxi?si=oqw6SQtxTVqJuoe2C_XrzQ omg this ones nice";
re = /track\/(\w+\?\w+=\w+)\s/;

match = track.match(re);
match[1];  # 1st parenthesized group: "1c3v8Ww4q8Vah92JBxAzxi?si=oqw6SQtxTVqJuoe2C_XrzQ"
match[0];  # the entire match: "track/1c3v8Ww4q8Vah92JBxAzxi?si=oqw6SQtxTVqJuoe2C_XrzQ "
```